# IKImageBrowserView "--ImageKit Error: reloadData called in non main thread"

Tags: cocoa, reloaddata, imagekit, ikimagebrowserview

I am writing a Cocoa Mac app which uses an IKImageBrowserView.
When I call the following:

```
[imageBrowserView reloadData];
```

The Debugger Console prints this:

```
--ImageKit Error: reloadData called in non main thread
```

I have tried placing the reloadData method in another method and then calling the following:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadMyView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

But I still get the same ImageKit Error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** FIXED **

The reason was a combination of using Bindings to populate my IKImageBrowserView from an NSArrayController, and an NSOperation which called save on it's own NSManagedObjectContext after populating the updates.

I had an Notification Observer for when the context in the NSOperation saved so I could then **mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification** to my main thread context, but I needed to perform this on the MainThread. The NSArrayController has **automaticallyPreparesContent** set to YES which  **"also registers as an observer of its managed object context"**. So as the merge was performed from the Notification this was being done on the same separate thread as the NSOperation, and as a result the NSArrayController was preparing it's content again on the separate thread, and then updating the IKImageBrowserView, again on the separate thread which was causing the error/warning.